# C++ Combining Class Inheritance and Templates

Tags: c++, class, templates, inheritance

I have an assignment that involves inheritance and templates. I'm supposed to create a music player program and create several classes that inherit the functions of the linked list.

What I'm getting thrown off on, is inheriting a class template, to a class that is required to **not have a template**.

This is what I have so far. This is the class that is being inherited:

```
#ifndef LINKED_LIST_
#define LINKED_LIST_

#include <memory>

#include "ListInterface.h"
#include "Node.h"

template <typename ItemType>
class LinkedList : public ListInterface<ItemType> {

// ...
```

This is the class that's going to take the functions from the base class:

```
#ifndef DISC_
#define DISC_

#include <memory>
#include "LinkedList.h"

class Disc : public LinkedList {

// ...
```

I understand that I need to pass the template through the LinkedList declaration for the second block of code. However, I'm unsure how to do this. Something that I tried was:

```
template <typename ItemType>
class Disc : public LinkedList<ItemType> {

// ...
```

But would this declare the Disc class as a template? That's what my instructor told me.
Thanks.

Comment: what type you want to have as `ItemType` ? Maybe `Disc` ? That would be `LinkedList<Disc>`

Comment: I want to leave ItemType as ItemType. Mainly because I'm not supposed to change the code for the LinkedList.h class. I'm fine with whatever name it's supposed to be. I won't be implementing them into my project, it's just the inheritance that I'm getting confused on.

Comment: i am not suggesting to change `LinkedList`, but `LinkedList` is just a template, to get a type that you can inherit from you have to choose for what type to instantiate it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> But would this declare the Disc class as a template?

Yes. If you want to have a type (not a template) that you can inherit from, you need to instantiate `LinkedList`. You can for example have a `LinkedList` of `Disc`s that would be `LinkedList<Disc>`. And `Disc` can be declared as

```
class Disc : public LinkedList<Disc> {};
```

Note that `LinkedList<Disc>` is not a template. It is a type like others, hence also `Disc` does not have to be a template. I had to do some guessing to choose the template parameter. I don't think `Disc` inheriting from a `LinkedList<Disc>` is a sound design. However, this is another possibility that would not be less odd:

```
class Disc : public LinkedList<int> {};
```

The point here is just to realize that `LinkedList<int>` is not a template, just like eg `std::vector<int>` is not a template.

Comment: I attempted this, and I got " 'LinkedList': 'Disk' is not a valid template type argument for parameter 'ItemType' ".

Comment: @Eric206 if you have compiler errors, you should include a [mcve] and the compiler error in the question.

Comment: @Eric206 or maybe a typo, your class is called `Disc` not `Disk`

Comment: Yeah, it was just a typo. I'm getting another error now, but I'll figure it out on my own (it's an error that's not related to this question anymore). Thanks for the help.